# Style TextAppearance.Holo not found

Tags: android, styles

I have been building this app for a while now and have not had any trouble with the themes until I updated to the latest platform tools today.  Now it's telling me

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Medium.Inverse'.
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Medium'.
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Large'.
```

[image: error messages]

This is the part of my styles.xml that is causing the problem but, as I said, it hasn't changed in months and worked fine until today!

```
<style name="BD.TextAppearance.Medium.Inverse" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Medium.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="BD.TextAppearance.Medium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">#666666</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>

<style name="BD.TextAppearance.Large" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#666666</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

-= EDIT =-
I started messing around with the values and it turns out that it does find these styles:

```
<style name="BD.TextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="BD.TextAppearance.Medium.Inverse" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

But not these:

```
<style name="BD.TextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="BD.TextAppearance.Medium.Inverse" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Light.Medium.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why this happened but I have found a way around it.  I copied the styles.xml file from the Android SDK and pasted it into my project and took out all of the styles that I wasn't using.  The I changed all of the 'parent' declarations to include the '@android:' prefix and added 'android:' after the '?' for all attributes.  This allows it to compile and run.  But like I said I would really like to find out why it broke in the first place!

Comment: Did you find the reason by now?

Comment: @CaseyB, were you compiling as part of the platform? I ask because it appears that TextAppearance.Holo.Light is not public for some reason (even though TextAppearance.Holo is public). If you were compiling with the platform, you'd be able to see these styles, but if you are compiling against the SDK, it would fail to find them. Just a thought.

Comment: No, I meant that I could see them in the res folder in the platform that comes with the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Medium.Inverse'.
```

I too face the Same problem what i did is that just i removed the

`parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Medium.Inverse"` attribute. It will works check it.

Comment: The issue with that is that it doesn't adopt the presets from those styles!  I guess I could just define every attribute.